# why PostgreSql Driver PGJDBC-NG giving Error

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, pgjdbc-ng

I am trying to connect using PGJDBC-NG Driver with my Postgres Db.
But on sql running it is giving error.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext does not implement the requested interface io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundInvoker
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
at [internal classes]
at hcl.common.filter.FilterToGetTimeOut.doFilterInternal(FilterToGetTimeOut.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at [internal classes]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
```

Comment: This seems unrelated to PostgreSQL or the JDBC driver - at least I see no trace of them in the stack trace.

Comment: No..that's same question asked by me